# How to get a Hibernate Type object for a (custom) UserType class

Tags: java, hibernate

I am looking for help on coding the `getPropertyTypes()` method when implementing the Hibernate `CompositeUserType` interface for defining a custom composite type that is made up of custom types.

When creating a custom composite type for Hibernate, you implement the `CompositeUserType` interface, of which one of the methods is:

```
Type[] getPropertyTypes();
```

This is easy enough to do if the component types are all basic types. It might look like this:

```
public Type[] getPropertyTypes() {
    return new Type[] {
      StringType.INSTANCE, 
      IntegerType.INSTANCE
    };
}
```

But how is this done when the component types are custom types?

Back in Hibernate v3.6, you could do:

```
public Type[] getPropertyTypes() {
    return new Type[] {
      Hibernate.custom(MyUserType1.class),
      Hibernate.custom(MyUserType2.class),
    };
}
```

Where `MyUserType1` and `MyUserType2` implement the `UserType` interface.

But I am now using Hibernate v5.3.22, and the `Hibernate.custom()` method is long gone.

Answer (score 0):

```
new org.hibernate.type.CustomType(new MyUserType1())
```

works for me.

Had the same question and came across this SO, so thought I'd put the answer I found down here.